# Angular2 - Webpack - Cordova Hybrid App white screen after splashscreen. HTML DOM rendering is taking more time

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, webpack

In Angular2-Cordova, hybrid app is working but white screen is showing for at-least 20s before the app content. I inspect the app in browser web-console, I found the below points,

> 1. DOM is not rendering in inspected browser web console. Angular2 HTML/CSS/JS loading is taking more time.
> 2. I tried to load to load custom splashscreen and hide it after 5000s and I tried to load the Webpack generated js files(Polyfill.bundle.js, app.bundle.js & vendor.bundle.js) in 3000s. I can see the custom splash screen but after 3000s loaded webpack js is taking time and the app gets hang for 3sec.

Solutions are welcome...

Comment: Your question is very broad. See [http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow](http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, you are doing the rendering job inside the app (JIT or Just In Time compilation)...
The solution would be to use [AOT (Ahead Of Time compilation)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html), so you don't have to parse and render your templates on the device, but on your development/build machine.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will try the Angular2 JIT and get back to you if any..

Comment: AOT, not JIT. JIT is the root of your problem.

Comment: Can you guide me to migrate from OnsenUI2+Angular2+Webpack1.4 to OnsenUI2+Angular2+Webpack2. I tried to migrate but fails with webpack error.